# Nginx try_files doesn't work inside server block

Tags: webserver, http, nginx, web

```
    http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    server {
        root /websites;
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        # don't work
        try_files /logo.png /logo.jpg /error;

        # works
        rewrite ^/e /error;

        # works
        # return 200 "$request_uri Handled by server block";

        location / {
            default_type text/plain;
            return 200 "Root prefix matched";
        }

        location /error {
            default_type text/plain;
            return 404 "Logo not found";
        }

    }
}
```

I want to know what is the cause of this evaluation, I couldn't find any reliable explanation neither on documentation nor on forums.

By the way I've experimented the following scenario:

- Removed `location / {}` block and it worked as intended. I know that when the request is made to the server it first evaluated by server block and then matched location blocks. But it seems `try_files` directive is ignored (WHY?!!). If I'm correct the last argument of `try_files` directive rewrites the URI so it should behave as `rewrite` directive. Both `rewrite` and `return` directives worked as intended, they evaluated  every time irrespective to whether there are location block matches or not.

I researched a lot to find reliable information explaining this situation, but I couldn't find. So I'm asking here for the answer or source about Nginx internals someone who knows.